# Opening more than one Chromium Window on startup

Tags: chromium, lxsession

for a information monitor i wanted to open different chromium windows on startup (The reason is because i use xdotool to switch between different websites and i dont get it to work if the Websites are in the same window (different tabs))
I wanted to use a basci code for startup:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
point.rpi
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized https://www.faz.net
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized https://google.com
```

It works perfectly if i dont specify the website on the second chromium line. But if specify
both so that i dont get one faz window and one empty window, it opens both in the same window and as two tabs. I dont know why it opens a new window if i dont specify the second website but puts it together if i specify it. Im lost right now so i hope you guys can help me

Comment: Where is the basic code located? What operating system do you use? Raspbian Buster?

Comment: Looks like the OP has these commands in lxsession autostart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open two chromium windows (and not have them "stick together" as 2 tabs in 1 window), simply add this to **both** commands in your lxsession autostart:

```
--new-window
```

I found that command line flag by typing this:

```
chromium-browser --help
```